# Overall CAGR calculation

Tags: calculation

I'm one of those data analysts who doesn't have a MBA, so I'm still figuring out the basics of finance as work gets assigned to me.

Here's the exact wording I was given:

> What's the unit cost inflation (CAGR) between 2010 and 2014?

In this case, I've got 20 rows, I've got the unit costs for each year. I got the year-over-year and 4-year CAGRs for each row no problem per the formula:

$$\textrm{CAGR}(t_0, t_n) = \left( \frac{V(t_n)}{V(t_0)} \right) ^{\frac{1}{t_n - t_0}} - 1$$

Now my problem arises: I need to get the CAGR for the entire category. I'm going to assume it's neither as simple as just summing/averaging the CAGR for each item, nor summing up the unit prices by year and running them through the formula.

Comment: Since you have 20 items, you have 20 CAGR's. The *overall CAGR* is ambiguous. If you know the relative importance of the 20 items you could weight the initial and final values of the items. Or you could average them (assume the importance is the same). Better seek some guidance from people who need this calculation...

Comment: @AlexC That was my thought also. Not quite a solution, but very affirming. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

CAGR is the growth rate that when applied to the base year and compounded over the entire time, generates the final value.
So to get CAGR you need to plugin base value, final value and duration to the formula to get the rate.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an overall CAGR for the category, it sounds like you can get an average price of the basket, and calculate the CAGR of this average price.